# Split string in groups by regular expression and check one group against condition

Tags: regex, linq, c#-4.0, split, comparison

I would like to solve a group comparison against a condition with regular expressions library.
My string is in this format:

**2_[1_2_2013]_10_16_00_PM**
"*1*"
"*2*"
"*2013*"

The square brackets represents the groups I would like to extract and compare with a custom date (*The Condition*), after DateTime parsing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this RegEx: `(?<=\d{1}_\[)\d{1,2}(?:_)\d{1,2}(?:_)\d{4}(?=\]_.+)`, then do the rest of your logic.

Comment: Why not format the condition date and do a much simpler check, against the target date,e g: `\d_1_2_1013_\d{2}_\d{2}_\d{2}_[A|P]M` ?

Comment: What represent the first digit (`2`)?

Comment: Does it need to be regex?  It seems to me you could just do `"2_1_2_2013_10_16_00_PM".Split('_').Skip(1).Take(3);`

Comment: @TheGreatCO Regex is faster and doesn't create temporary strings. If you need to parse even moderate log files, this is a serious concern

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos regex is usually not faster that basic string ops. Yes, it may create fewer strings, but sometimes ease of coding and understanding is more useful than optimizing code for a few cycles on a modern processor.  On top of that, the question is clearly tagged `linq`

Comment: I use Regex and LINQ to parse log files. A single 50MB file can contain a few million rows in which case splitting strings takes significantly larger amounts of RAM and CPU than a regex. Now multiply by 7 to get a week's logs. By the way, splitting won't detect an invalid string until you actually try to parse it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos so not use LINQ for parse log files :-)

Comment: @Grundy I think you misunderstood what I meant. Using LINQ doesn't mean you can'tuse a regex. When working with large amounts of data, combining both is a very powerful combination (just think Hadoop/Splunk). Memory and CPU consumption is a very real concern in such cases and string manipulations end up costing a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the target date is the same for all searches, you could format it as a string and try a regex match against a regex that matches this specific date, eg:

```
var dateString=targetDate.ToString("d_M_yyyy");
var pattern="\d_" + dateString + "_\d{2}_\d{2}_\d{2}_[A|P]M";
var regex=new Regex(pattern);
...
regex.IsMatch(inputLine);
```

If the date changes based on some criteria, you can extract the entire date element as a group and parse its value with [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var regex=new Regex("\d_(?<date>\d{1,2}_\d{1,2}_\d{4})_\d{2}_\d{2}_\d{2}_[A|P]M";
...
var match=regex.Match(inputLine);
if(match.Success)
{
    var dateString=match.Groups["date"].Value;
    DateTime dateValue;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString,"d_M_yyyy",
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None,out dateValue)
    {
       //use dateValue
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case would be several text files stored in the same directory, which has different names with dates each one, so in case of date ranges won't work I believe. I need to check each date part on each one and compare it with the date boundary parameter I receive.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. You can extract the date part with the second regex then compare the resulting date against the range you need.